# Move Chrome's address bar to the bottom

Tags: chrome-for-android

From [How to Move Chrome Address Bar to Bottom or Top](https://mashtips.com/enable-chrome-home-move-address-bar/), Chrome's address bar can be moved to the bottom by using experimental features from `chrome://flags`. However, it has been deprecated since Chrome 66.

> Google deprecated the bottom address Bar ‘Chrome Home’ in favor of a new 
>   ‘Chrome Duet’ interface from Chrome Stable to 66. [...]. If you want to use this Home
>   Flag, you have to downgrade to Chrome Stable 65.

Are there any other possible ways to move Chrome's address bar to the bottom?